# How to set seller's address into invoice automatically generated by PrestaShop 1.7.6.7?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I don't know how to set seller's data, ex. name, street, code and city, that are saved into invoice.

Answer (score 0):

These information are taken from contact info:
[image]

For other options, you can have look into orders > invoices.
If you need more customisation, then you need to have access to FTP, to manualy edit the .tpl files (so you'd need to know some html).
[Here they explain it more](https://magento-asia.blogspot.com/2017/05/presetashop-17x-how-to-edit-pdf-invoices.html).